# PDO FETCH_CLASS when fields and columns have different names

Tags: php, pdo

From the documentation [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) and [FETCH_CLASS](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php) :

```
<?php
class fruit {
    public $name;
    public $colour;
}

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "fruit");
var_dump($result);
?>
```

It often happens that columns names are different from the fields defined in the classes. I'm wondering if there is some clean way to get the fields of the class populated when the query fetches different columns names :

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT f_name, f_colour FROM fruit");
```

Is there a generic solution to map columns name to fiels ? I tried several combinations for the FETCH_MODE, hoping one of them would pass the results into the constructor, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It often happens that columns names are different from the fields defined in the classes.

**It shouldn't happen in the first place.** The very purpose of this fetch mode is to make properties assignment simple, when column names are considered to match class properties. So, programmers make use for the same naming all the way through - for the SQL table column names, for HTML form input fields names, as well as corresponding classes properties. And that would be true *generic solution*.

But well, if you want it, there are 2 solutions, SQL based, by using aliases in the query, and OOP based, where you can employ magic `__set()` method in which you can implement whatever rename logic you wish.

Comment: "So, programmers make use for the same naming all the way through - for the SQL table column names, for HTML form input fields names, as well as corresponding classes properties." If you ever, even back in 2015, told me you were going to do this while answering a question in a job interview, I'd straight up ask you to leave immediately.

Comment: @designermonkey Why is that bad style to name everything the same throughout the whole software? 
What would be a better solution? Why would you kick him out ?